# Remove navigation from a single page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to remove the menubar from the following page: [demopage](https://mimsi.dk/base/). I can see the menu I have to remove is inside the html tag `nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation"`.

The page has the id 3222. I therefore tried to remove the menubar with the following CSS, but that is not working:

```
.page-id-3222 {
  display:none;
 }
```

I checked if I am hitting the class with setting all the links to be red, and that is working. So the question is how I hide the html tag `nav`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Wordpress you always have access to classes in the body tag. Just find the `page-id-XXXX` and add the CSS to hide it.

```
body.page-id-XXXX .mega-menu-wrap {
    display: none
}
```

If you are looking to hide a single nav item find the corresponding item in the navigation. Don't forget, if you're hiding something thru CSS it won't work if you create a new page as the page ID's will change.

```
body.page-id-XXXX .mega-menu-wrap .mega-menu-item-1702 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I just tried your suggestion on the page i linked to in my question, but the menu is still there?

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing. You're link leads to a 404-page.

Comment: Try load the page now. I just puslished the page. Is it working?

Comment: `.page-id-3222 nav.navbar-collapse {display:none!important;}` hides the navbar.

`.page-id-3222 .themo_cart_icon {display:none;}` hides the cart-button

Comment: Yes that is working, thank you. I just updated the page. I can see the sticky header is still there? Can I set the same code for the sticky header?

Comment: You can! But do you want to keep the logo in the upper left corner? Then just add `.page-id-3222 .navbar-static-top .mega-menu-wrap {display:none!important;}`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bootstrap that's why you need to use

```
.post=3222 nav {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and remove `!important` from `.navbar-collapse.collapse` and `nav.navbar-collapse.bs-navbar-collapse`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OizSl.png)

Comment: That would affect all the pages there is using the menubar, if I start removing `.navbar-collapse.collapse` and `nav.navbar-collapse.bs-navbar-collapse`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Customize - Additional CSS and write,

```
.collapse {display:none!important;}
```

`.navbar-collapse {
display:none!important;
}`

```
.bs-navbar-collapse {display:none!important;}
```